# Run code for every Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, pageload

I need to do HTML code manipulation for every loaded page in my ASP.NET application. Where is the best place to put my method? Put code into every web page Page_Load event in not very smart, what other alternatives?

Comment: Define "HTML code manipulation."  Does this need to happen server-side, or can it happen client-side?

Comment: Server side due to its complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

consider using custom HttpModule

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

or in Global.asax you can hook up desired event in Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute:

```
void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;

            if (context.Handler is Page)
            {
                Page page = (Page)context.Handler;
                page.Load += ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to think of!  I have a site with .aspx pages, but also .html pages and I want to run this code any time any of them are loaded.

Answer (score 10):

If I get you right, you've something which logically needs to happen in Page_Load, but you want to avoid the obvious issues with duplicating that code in each case.

I would define a page base for the project (there are other advantages in doing so too), that all page code-behinds inherit from, and which itself inherits from System.Web.UI.Page. Then, have it do the required work before or after the Page_Load as appropriate.

Alternatively, it may be possible to do the HTML manipulation work you talk of in a filter.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new base class which inherits System.Web.UI.Page, then in each of your code behind pages, update them to inherit from this new base class rather than System.Web.UI.Page.

In this new base class you can stick the method which you can call from the Page_Load on all of your pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a JavaScript function once and import it into every page.

Comment: I need to do manipulation using c# code because it is very complex.